# Javascript/Css : Cannot move background with positionBackground

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I want to move my background infinite, to do that i code this :

```
    html, body {
    margin : 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: url('../assets/img/ship.cur'), auto;
    background-color : #000;
}

#background {
    position : absolute;
    background-image: url('../assets/img/littlestars.png');
    height : 720px;
    width : 1280px;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/home.css">
  <script language=javascript src="../js/navigate.js"> </script>
  <script language=javascript src="../js/background.js"> </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="onLoad(); loadBG();">
  <div id="background"> </div>

</body>
</html>

function loadBG() {
    window.setInterval(moveStars, 100);
}

function moveStars() {
    var bg = document.getElementById("background");
     bg.style.backgroundPosition += 10;
}
```

But it doesn't work... if i can't display backgroundPosition.

Some ideas ? It's the good way to create javascript animation ? Thx.

Comment: Where is `onLoad();` defined? Try changing your body tag to `onLoad="loadBG();"`

Comment: `=+ 10` what? Pixels? Along the x or y axis? You can't just add 10 to a string and hope that it works. This is also not a good way to animate things, have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

backgroundPosition is a property that indicates x,y position of backrogund in units, not a single number.

You need to do something like:

```
var posx = 0;
function moveStars() {
    var bg = document.getElementById("background");
    posx+=10;
    bg.style.backgroundPosition = posx+"px 0";
}
```